# Fix 'Enter passphrase for key: '

Tags: ssh

My SSH private key would automatically be unlocked earlier because I guess it was configured with Seahorse. It would just ask for my password and handle things on its own.

For some weird reason, it doesn't seem to work anymore. I am sure that I did *not* change any setting. Now whenever I try to log in to a remote server, it asks me for:

```
 Enter passphrase for key: '$PATH_TO_KEY'
```

This is annoying! How can I fix it? I know I have to use `ssh-agent` and I tried to add the key but it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What happens when you try `ssh-add`?

Answer (score 2):

A fix depends on how you manage your ssh keys. From what you've wrote I guess that you are using ssh-agent. If that's true `ssh-add -l` should give you a list of keys that are currently managed ... or an error if the agent hasn't been started.

ssh-agent is usually started by one of the shell init files or one of the X init files or by pam_ssh. You should find out where you start ssh-agent (if it's started at all) to encircle the problem.

Alternatively, you can use GnuPG as an ssh-agent replacement. When starting the gpg-agent you can add the `--enable-ssh-support` option. Again, gpg-agent must be started somewhere, preferably upon login.

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute ssh-agent
2. Execute ssh-add
3. Export the two variables SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID in any terminal session you want to use automatic unlocking of ssh keys.